# How to get value of query param array in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:3009/mac/view/:userId?ot-replace[0]=kin43
```

I need the value of `ot-replace[0]`

In the controller I am using

```
 @RequestParam(name="ot-replace", required=false)String[] regexReplace
```

Also tried using

```
 @RequestParam(name="ot-replace", required=false)List<String> regexReplace
```

I always get null.
Not sure what is the issue here

Comment: Try `List<String>` instead of `String[]`

Comment: @sm3sher already tried still it is null

Comment: try using @RequestParam("ot-replace[0]"), also please tell me about the type of data, Is it sent in the form of a String array( means multiple value)

Comment: @PuneetKundliya it needs to be a dynamic approach as I have an array multiple values could be passed in query param as `ot-replace[0], ot-replace[1], ot-replace[2]` .....

Comment: try using @RequestParam("ot-replace[{id}]") String[] regexReplace or List<String> regexReplace

Comment: @PuneetKundliya doesn't work. Get this error `ot-replace[{id}] for method parameter type List is not present"`

Comment: I cannot think of any other issue, You can change your url parameter name for sending the data like "ot-replace=kin43,value2,vlue3" OR go through https://www.taogenjia.com/2021/06/30/How-to-Receive-Array-Data-in-Spring-MVC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL should like this.

```
http://127.0.0.1:3009/mac/view/:userId?ot-replace=kin43,value2,vlue3
```

then
you can get a String[].

```
ot-replace[0]=kin43
ot-replace[1]=value2
ot-replace[2]=value3
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use a POST methood when excute your url and set your array in the request body.

Comment: This kind of request works well with node js. Ideally it should also work with spring.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).